# Clear a ui-select dropdown field or provide an empty value

Tags: magento2, ui-select

I wanted to add a little filter to a dropdown and did so with a ui-select component which works almost perfectly except once set I am struggling to then unet the value. Only other values are shown and there is no blank option.

I added this field to category_form.xml

```
    <field name="category_brands_root" component="Harrigo_CustomMenu/js/components/select-brand">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Harrigo\CustomMenu\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Brands</item>
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">60</item>
                <item name="filterOptions" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="multiple" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">string</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
                <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Assign Category to Brand Links</item>
                <item name="disableLabel" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Assign Category to Brand Links</label>
            <elementTmpl>ui/grid/filters/elements/ui-select</elementTmpl>
            <componentType>field</componentType>
            <listens>
                <link name="${ $.namespace }.${ $.namespace }:responseData">setParsed</link>
            </listens>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <select>
                <settings>
                    <options class="Harrigo\CustomMenu\Model\Category\Attribute\Source\Brands"/>
                </settings>
            </select>
        </formElements>
    </field>
```

Where Harrigo_CustomMenu/js/components/select-brand.js looks like below:

```
define([
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/ui-select'
], function (Select) {
  'use strict';
  return Select.extend({
    /**
     * Parse data and set it to options.
     *
     * @param {Object} data - Response data object.
     * @returns {Object}
     */
    setParsed: function (data) {
        var option = this.parseData(data);
        if (data.error) {
            return this;
        }
        this.options([]);
        this.setOption(option);
        this.set('newOption', option);
    },
    /**
     * Normalize option object.
     *
     * @param {Object} data - Option object.
     * @returns {Object}
     */
    parseData: function (data) {
        return {
            value: data.category_brands_root.entity_id,
            label: data.category_brands_root.name
        };
    }
  });
});
```

My source pulls data from below:

```
public function getAllOptions()
{
    $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand');
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    return $options;
}
```

This works great as in shows all options has a working search at the top and saves fine however, this is an optional field and may need to be unset at some point. There is no empty value or way of clearing to its original state like when it initialises originally on an empty value showing "Select...".

I have got an empty value in my options array however they get hidden. The only thing I could think was something like below where a space or 0 is used (which will never match) however, bit of a botch seems messy and I do not like it:

```
    $attribute = $this->eavConfig->getAttribute('catalog_product', 'brand');
    $options = $attribute->getSource()->getAllOptions();
    $empty = ['value' => ' ', 
                'label' => 'Select...'];
    array_unshift($options , $empty);

    return $options;
```

Any other ideas?

Comment: Pease, navigate to the product edit page inside admin area, select some categories and then execute the following JavaScript code in your dev console: ```require('uiRegistry').get('index = category_ids').clear()``` Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Yeah that is it. require('uiRegistry').get('index = category_brands_root').clear() works great. Do you know a nice way to implement this?

Comment: Well I say that, for me it visibly clears it however saving does not seem to save the cleared value after running that in console.